# problem with beamer's sound command

Tags: beamer, multimedia

```
\documentclass[pdflatex]{beamer}

\usepackage{multimedia} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Music}
  \sound[channels=2,bitspersample=16,samplingrate=44100,encoding=Signed,autostart,inlinesound]{}{Laute.aif}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

produces 11 error messages, starting with the very enlightening:

```
! Undefined control sequence
\mm@pageadditionalaction ...e \beamer@pdfpageattr

/AA{}>>\END \ifx \mm@pdfp

l.10 \end{frame}
```

Laute.aif plays with both foobar and vlc, so is presumably a valid file. These players also told me the properties of the file used in the options. The command I copied and pasted from beameruserguide section 14.2. Converting the .aif to an .au file doesn't solve the pproblem. How do I get this to work?

Removing the autostart option or replacing multimedia.sty with an older version allows this to compile correctly, but even in the latter case no autostart occurs and the music contains a lot of noise and distortion. Removing the inlinesound option corrects the latter problem. I could not open .mp3 files at all.

Comment: `autostart` seems to be the problematic option.

Comment: Was working fine with beamer version 3.40 - so the problem is somewhere between then and now.

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere in this commit https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/c37830892de89d6c58ad0e530cd310bc2a4d7bd1

Comment: As a temporary workaround you could place this old version in your working directory: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/af183ed8226a1d59903a96082720838984d3284c/base/multimedia/multimedia.sty

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
\makeatletter
\let\beamer@pdfpageattr\pdfpageattr
\makeatother
```

should do the job until the next release (assuming pdfTeX).